# How to remove 'By term' and 'View' tab being displayed at top of pages?

Tags: 6, taxonomy-terms, routes

On a Drupal 6 site, I have these annoying 'View' and 'By term' tabs being displayed on all node types. I am wondering how to remove/disable both of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'By term' seems to be generated by one of the views in Organic groups: posts_by_term. You should be able to disable it at admin/build/views. Here's the issue https://drupal.org/node/1635082.

The View tab should not be displayed if it's the only tab, for example for authenticated users who don't have permission to edit the node.

Removing the View and Edit tabs, should you want that, is a bit complicated because you still might need them in some situations. Here's a pretty thorough conversation about that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3530756/how-to-hide-edit-view-tabs.

Comment: You are right. to be exact, the 'By term| view' tabs were created by posts_by_term. After deleting the view, the tabs are gone. Thanks man.

Comment: The View tab is core stuff, not OG, but won't be displayed alone.